# Airflow Webserver Not Opening in Safari

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-webserver

I'm currently trying to use `airflow` .

I have been following a series of tutorials to get started on constructing DAGs, so the database has been initialized, and now I want to startup the webserver by commanding through the terminal:
`airflow webserver -p 8080`.

I consequently get the webpage http://0.0.0.0:8080 (2843), however when I click, I receive the following error: "Failed to Open Page: Safari can't open the page "0.0.0.0:8080" because the page's address isn't valid". I have tried restarting this multiple times, restarting my computer, trying different ports (ie. 8080, 8088, 8081, etc) to no avail. Can some provide an actual solution as I have been stuck here for 2 weeks now?

*Refer to previous question for attempts.

Comment: I understand you're running airflow using local installation? which version of airflow is it? Did you export AIRFLOW_HOME variable before running webserver and scheduler? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.7.2/start.html I followed this and seems to ok. I'd recommend using docker-compose approach if you can, its quite straightforward and cleaner imo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to share the logs of web server to answer this question better. There can be n number of reasons so please put logs and output of

```
docker ps -a
```

Try other links ->

1. http://0.0.0.0:8080/login
2. http://0.0.0.0:8080/home